# Java: Encapsulating if-return statement in a method call for cleaner, more concise code?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style, code-cleanup

I'm learning Java as well as studying books on code design.

I am wondering, is it possible in Java to have an `if` statement encapsulated in a method call that allows one to somehow exit the parent method if the `boolean` is false?

What I'm wondering is that if if I can further distill the following code

```
public void addStock (String stock) {

boolean stockNameIsValid = testStringForValidStockName(stock);
    if (stockNameIsValid == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "Invalid text entered. Stock ticker names may only include upper-case alphabetical letters.", "Invalid Text Entry Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

boolean stockAlreadyExistsInPanel = testForStockExistenceInListingPanel(stock); 
    if(stockAlreadyExistsInPanel == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "The same stock cannot be entered twice into the list of stocks being watched.", "Redundant Stock Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    controller.addStockToDb(stock);

}
```

into something like

```
public void addStock(String stock){
    giveErrorAndReturnIfStockNameInvalid(stock);
    giveErrorAndReturnIfStockCannotBeFound(stock);
    controller.addStockToDb(stock);
}
```

I'm wondering if doing this is possible because my IDE can't extract the code above any further, and having my code shaped in the second way above I think would communicate intent better and have a higher level of abstraction than the initial example.

I have this idea because I'm currently reading Uncle Bob's "Clean Code" book, and inside it says that methods ultimately should be as short as you can make them. If I encapsulate lower-level logic within method calls then it leaves the code reflecting higher-level logic. This makes the code easier to understand because it requires less of the developer's mental resources to get a general concept of what each part of the code does.

My goal here is to eliminate the reader from actually having to analyze the implementations details of the code here unless it's absolutely necessary. So instead of having to read through an entire method to comprehend it, the reader can instead get a more abstract representation of the logic of my code.

Comment: you could throw an Exception

Comment: **Never compare a `boolean` to `true` or `false`**. `if(x == true)` should **always** be written as `if(x)`. Comparing explicitly is not only ugly but also errorprone - `if(x = true)` will also compile (5 points if you can tell me what it does).

Comment: @BoristheSpider On  the other hand use of `if(!x)` should also be discouraged. Because it is not quite readable and sometimes your mind miss the *point* in this line in complex application. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ask yourself the following question: Should the `addStock` method also be responsible for displaying an error message? (Keep in mind that you are already trying to _clean code_.

Comment: @TAsk what would you suggest as an alternative? `if(x == false)` has the same issue as comparing to true and `if(x != true)` presumably has the same issue a `if(!x)` while being considerably uglier. I would say that if someone cannot spot an `!` in an `if` statement then they probably shouldn't be programming.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Alternative can be, just avoid to check `false` in `if`, if possible. `if(x)` is fine and `else` part can be used to handle `false`. Agree, that it's not always possible and we may come to the point when we need to use `if(!x)`.  I must agree with your last statement! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use Exceptions, below pseudo code explains the same:

```
public void addStock(String stock){
    try {
        isStockNameValid(stock);
        isStockExists(stock);
        controller.addStockToDb(stock);
   } catch(IllegalArgumentException exe) {

   }
}

public boolean isStockNameValid(stock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      //check stock name is valid, if not
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stock Name already exists");
}

public boolean isStockExists(stock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      //check stock exists, if not
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stock Name already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If parameter to addStock method is illegal, the methods could throw an illegal argument exception, for example:

```
public void giveErrorAndReturnIfStockNameInvalid(String stock)
{
    // TODO: Check stock name
    if(stock...)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stock has no valid name:"+stock);
    }
}
```

notice this (IllegalArgumentException) is an unchecked exception, so you could get runtime exceptions uncaught if not handled in the calling method, another option could be to create a new domain specific exception like "InvalidStockException" and make it checked, so anyone using this method will be forced to add a try-catch block just in case something goes wrong and show the error message.